# how give permission for reset apache without admin permission?

Tags: permissions, apache2, groups

my user don't have admin permission and i do not want to give admin permission to them.

how give permission that they see log and reset and change config in apache?

is there apache admin group that add user to this group?

Answer (score 0):

In order to let the user see the log files, I would suggest changing the group ownership of /var/log/apache and all files in that directory to group `www`. You'll likely have to edit `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` to keep the new group permissions. Then add your user to the group `www`

Use `sudo` permissions to let the user reset the service. Using `visudo`, add a line like `username ALL=(root) /usr/sbin/service apache2 start,/usr/sbin/service apache2 stop,/usr/sbin/service apache2 restart`.

I would not allow the user to edit the apache config file. It would be difficult to give them permissions to do this without the possibility of them breaking system security.

Comment: this case have 20 machin and it's difficult.is there a group that apache is a member of it?